# Truncate text in RichTextBox and TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I am using `RichTextBox` and `TextBox` for showing some information which is collected during several days. So there are a lot of strings inside it after couple days and I get `OutOfMemory` exception. I think this error occurs because of lots of data. Is there some properties or functions which allow to limit number of strings inside `RichTextBox` and `TextBox`? I need to truncate only old strings which are in the beggining of list. For instance, take a look at picture below:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: When adding an item: `if (reached items limit) { remove(firstItem); } add(newItem);`

Comment: Also, if your text's length doesn't come close to `int.MaxValue`, it must mean your OutOfMemoryException isn't caused by over-texting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created simple code which allows me to resolve this problem.
For `TextBox`:

```
if (limitLines>0 && simpleTextBox.LineCount > limitLines)
{
   string tempText = "";
   for (int i = simpleTextBox.LineCount-limitLines; i < simpleTextBox.LineCount; i++)
   {
      tempText += simpleTextBox.GetLineText(i);
   }                                                        
   simpleTextBox.Clear();
   simpleTextBox.Text = tempText;

}
simpleTextBox.AppendText(data);
```

For `RichTextBox`:

```
        TextRange tr = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
        tr.Text = text + "\r\n";           
        tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, solidColorBrush);

        if (limitLines > 0 && richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Count > limitLines)
        {
            for (int i = richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Count - limitLines; i < richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Count; i++)
                richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Remove(richTextBox.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock);
        }
```

I hope it helps to someone else!